# Foreground Color of Custom Button (ControlPresenter)

Tags: wpf, controls, controltemplate

I am attempting to define a global button style in App.xaml, and it's mostly working as I expect.  However, I just cannot figure out how to get the Foreground to work correctly.  No matter what I do, I am getting the style of the default TextBlock (which sets the color to White).

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3, 5" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" 
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="gridMainButton"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" 
                                            CenterX="0.5"
                                            CenterY="0.5" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates" >
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                              Duration="0"
                                              To="0.85" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 StrokeThickness="2"
                                 Stroke="{StaticResource standardBackground}"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource standardBackground}" />
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Margin="4, 8"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I guess I could change the ContentPresenter to a TextBlock, which would be ok for this particular application, but I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Markus Hütter said, the problem is probably that you have an implicit Style for a `TextBlock` defined and when the `Button Content` is set to a string, a `TextBlock` will be created where you have the `ContentPresenter` in the Template. This `TextBlock` will pick up the implicit Style and that's why you're getting this problem.

You can disable the implicit Style for a `TextBlock`s that is created in place for a string by specifying a `DataTemplate` for `string`. Add the following to App.xaml

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                      DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
                </TextBlock.Resources>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--...-->
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be using a custom style for textblock (if you say Foreground color is white) lets call this *StandardTextBlockStyle*.

Within your button style inside the outer grid. include this:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMainButton">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource StandardTextBlockStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!-- ...-->
</Grid>
```

this should override the default TextBlock style.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, there was a global TextBlock style and I was not able to override it in other controls where custom color/font was needed.

Based on [Fredrik Hedblad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318425/fredrik-hedblad) & [Pavlo Glazkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556449/pavlo-glazkov) (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327819/setting-foreground-color-of-entire-window)) responses, the following solution worked for me:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground),
                        FallbackValue={StaticResource Colors_ThemeForeground_SCBrush}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource Colors_ThemeForeground_SCBrush}}"/>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Thanks,
RDV