# Foreground property behavior confusion

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have a custom control like this:

```
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    private StackPanel panel;

    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        panel = (StackPanel)GetTemplateChild("root");
        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "TextBlock added in the OnApplyTemplate method" });

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

and its control template is like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <StackPanel Name="root">
                    <TextBlock>TextBlock added in ControlTemplate</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

then I use it in the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:app1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <app1:CustomControl1 Foreground="Red">

    </app1:CustomControl1>
</Grid>
```

if I run it, it'll be like this:

[image]

So my confusion is that the TextBlock in ControlTemplate follows the local value of Foreground. But the TextBlock added in the OnApplyTemplate method follows the value from the style.

But what I want is a TextBlock that only follows the style when no local value is present.

So why do the two TextBlocks behave differently and how can I get a TextBlock that only follows the style when no local value is present?

> Note: How can I make the TextBlocks inside of the custom control not
>   affected by an implicit style in the Resources of the Grid(which
>   contains the custom control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply local value for `Foreground` you are applying to the `CustomControl`, whereas in the style you are applying only to `TextBlock` that makes lot of difference. Get rid of `Grid.Resources` and move your style setter directly in `ControlTemplate` and it will work as expected.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <StackPanel Name="root">
                    <TextBlock>TextBlock added in ControlTemplate</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to fix the issue. But I wanted to get a Custom Control that only follows the style(defined in the Grid.Resources) when no local value is present.

Comment: Then your style in `Grid.Resources` should be for `CustomControl1` and not for `TextBlock`. `<Style TargetType="{x:Type app1:CustomControl1}"> <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter> </Style>`

Comment: thanks, but my real problem is that I want to know why do the two TextBlocks behave differently. and I want a custom control that does not get interrupted when a style for textblock is present.

Comment: Meaning that textblock style isn't meant for the CustomControl but for other controls in the grid ?. You shouldn't be using implicit styles then. Give x:Key value to the `Grid.Resources` style. Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381018/override-typed-textblock-style-for-contentpresenter-in-wpf