# Unset a value in a custom Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I my WPF application I'd like to change the text color by setting Foreground on the main Window like

```
<Window Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
</Window>
```

This works fine for TextBlocks, but if I add a Button, the font there stays black, since Button has a Setter for Foreground in its default style. can I make a new default style for Button based on the original one, but removing the Foregound setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you could try using a base style in an appropriate resource collection (e.g. at the application level in App.xaml), and then create an implicit style for each type of control based on this base style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="DefaultControlStyle">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultControlStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultControlStyle}" />        
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultControlStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultControlStyle}" />
```

You could also use a relative source binding trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328283/248164).

Comment: This approach makes it a little more difficult to change the foreground color for some UI parts based on triggers (Say, you have a ContentPresenter that should represent some error, contaning multiple child elements, and want to set Foreground to Red for the entire Content based on a trigger on the ContentPresenters parent).

Comment: I've just found some similar approaches here - I don't know if any of these are preferable - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327819/wpf-setting-foreground-color-of-entire-form

Comment: Pavlo Glazkov's answer works very well, thanks! Do you wish to edit your answer, so that I can accept it or should I post my own?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the link to the relative source trick.